# ERROR ashx could not create type 'jQueryUploadTest.Thumbnail' in jquery-file-upload?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, file-upload, multifile-uploader

I want to use the [jQuery file uploader](https://github.com/swhitley/jQuery-File-Upload) , and followed this [sample](http://www.webtrendset.com/2011/06/22/complete-code-example-for-using-blueimp-jquery-file-upload-control-in-asp-net/)[Complete code example using blueimp jQuery file upload control in Asp.Net.] .

I copied the css ,js , image and the *.ashx file into my project, but when I'm running that, I'm receiving following error

> could not create type 'jQueryUploadTest.Thumbnail' in Thumbnail.ashx
>   file

Here is the ASHX code:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" CodeBehind="Thumbnail.ashx.cs" Class="jQueryUploadTest.Thumbnail" %>
```

and the Thumbnail.ashx.cs code:

```
using System.Web;

namespace jQueryUploadTest {
    public class Thumbnail : IHttpHandler {

        public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
            context.Response.WriteFile(context.Server.MapPath("~/JQueryFileUpload/images/default_thumb.jpg"));
        }

        public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
    }
}
```

Also I'm getting same error for 'FileTransferHandler.ashx'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i copied the ashx.cs files to app-code directory.
everythings it's ok.[solved]

Comment: I tried that and it did not work in my case. Besides, the whole idea about publishing is you do not send your code base over only the .dll files.